# vector.push_back() intellisense error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, vector

I have the following struct

```
struct foo{
    vector<foo*> cntns;
};
```

and the following function

```
void createLink(foo *i1, foo *i2){
    i1->cntns.push_back(i2);
    i2->cntns.push_back(i1);
}
```

but I get the error

```
2   IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=foo*, _Alloc=std::allocator<foo*>]" matches the argument list
        argument types are: (foo*)
        object type is: std::vector<foo*, std::allocator<foo*>>
```

Code seems to compile fine, anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Side note: prefer `vector<std::unique_ptr<foo>>` if possible.  Why use a vector when you have to manually clean up its contents?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by that? Isn't `vector<std::unique_ptr<foo>>` a vector?

Comment: If you have a vector of pointers, and those pointers (what they point to) are dynamically allocated, then you have to loop through the vector and `delete` each one before the vector goes out of scope or you "lose" the pointers in some other way.  The vector doesn't clean up your dynamically allocated memory for you, it cleans up its own storage.  It simply allocates storage for a bunch of pointers.

Comment: @EdS. The function name "createLink" suggests that the vector<foo*> members do not actually own the objects.  Therefore, unique_ptr would not work.  In fact, the above case creates a circular reference which standard smart pointers cannot resolve (you need a weak reference).  But that's OK as long as whatever does own the objects does properly clean them up.

Comment: @MooseBoys: Yeah, I saw the same thing in the example.  I used "if possible" intentionally here because I don't know the semantics.  You can always use `shared_ptr` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this is an Intellisense error, since the code will compile and work fine.

However if you really want to get rid of the Intellisense errors, I found making it a member function gets rid of the complaints:

```
struct foo
{
    vector<foo *> cntns;

    void createLink(foo * i2)
    {
        this->cntns.push_back(i2);
        i2->cntns.push_back(this);
    }
};
```